# Iterating a function over several cells

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a table of numbers that represent hours worked each day by several employees.  Each cell is one day for one employee.  Some cells include an "*" character denoting that those hours do not contribute to the departmental total.  When calculating the departmental total, I simply do a sum of all the cells and calc ignores those values that include the asterisks.  However, when I calculate the sum of the hours for the individual employee, I want to include those hours.

After doing some experimentation, I've arrived at the following clunky formula:

```
=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(C22,"*","")),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D22,"*","")),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(E22,"*","")),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(F22,"*","")),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(G22,"*","")),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(H22,"*","")),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(I22,"*","")))
```

While this works, it's terrible!  Is there a way to iterate a set of functions over a set of cells?  Something like:

```
=SUM(ITERATE_FUNCTION(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(X,"*","")),C22:I22))
```

Or is there an easier way to accomplish my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Calc, there is one super-power function for working with multiple values: [SUMPRODUCT](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMPRODUCT_function).  With a little creativity, it can do just about anything.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(C22:I22;"*";"")))
```

It acts as an array function but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is not needed, making things *much* easier.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(D22:I22),"*","")))
```

Press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER when you're finished typing it in so the formula becomes an array formula, the formula will then look like this:

```
{=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(D3:H3),"*","")))}
```

Comment: I changed the cell range to all the individual cells (d3,e3,etc).  That cleared the error, but I just get the values of the cells stuck together.

Comment: For some reason `<CTRL><SHIFT><ENTER>` didn't show up in my answer. Fixed now

Comment: The ctrl-shift-enter didn't work, but I did get it to work using the function wizard "array" check box.